# Is InnoDB module in Mysql important for Drupal?

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-6, innodb

Is InnoDB module in Mysql important for Drupal ?

Do you know modules that are based on InnoDB ?

I was considering to remove it to improve my server performances...

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB allows ACID transactions to be performed. ACID stand for **A** tomic, **C** onsistent, **I** ndependent and **D** urable.

If you are running an e-commerce portal, a CRM module, or any other software that may be affected by the consequences of a failed DB transactions, you need InnoDB.

If you run a highly visited web site, a BitTorrent tracker or something that is highly stressed but not critically affected by inconsistencies in the DB, then you can drop InnoDB for MyISAM.

Or, you can drop InnoDB if Drupal (sorry, I'm no expert in that) doesn't use `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK` SQL statements

In the past, I had to disable InnoDB in MySQL for memory reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal supports InnoDb, but **does not depend on it**. Review Drupal's [system requirements](http://drupal.org/requirements):

> Note: Drupal supports MyISAM and InnoDB table types. NDB tables (MySQL Cluster) are not supported.

As for modules, most should be database agnostic. I would be surprised if any depended on InnoDb, as most Drupal users won't be using it.

Comment: Note that with Drupal 7, InnoDB will be set as the default storage engine.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7 defaults to InnoDB which if unavailable will force the use of MyISAM. FWIW, some modules do require InnoDB. http://drupal.org/project/transaction is an obvious one that comes to mind.